# SQL Alchemy not handling single quotes in column name

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

For multi-index dataframes, Pandas writes the column names to the database in the format `('index1[i]', 'index2[i]')`.  When trying to save to the DB this results in the following error:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/code/core/store/views.py" in from_reducer
  50.         serializer.save(self.get_object(), background_job)

File "/code/core/store/serializers.py" in save
  275.             self.context.get("request").tenant,

File "/code/core/store/serializers.py" in _XXXX_ingestion_serializer_async_save
  71.             XXXX.dataframe = dataframe

File "/code/core/store/models.py" in dataframe
  88.             con=engine,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py" in to_sql
  2130.                    dtype=dtype)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py" in to_sql
  450.                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py" in to_sql
  1127.         table.insert(chunksize)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py" in insert
  641.                 self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py" in _execute_insert
  616.         conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py" in execute
  948.             return meth(self, multiparams, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py" in _execute_on_connection
  269.             return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py" in _execute_clauseelement
  1060.             compiled_sql, distilled_params

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py" in _execute_context
  1200.                 context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py" in _handle_dbapi_exception
  1416.                 util.reraise(*exc_info)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py" in reraise
  249.         raise value

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py" in _execute_context
  1170.                         context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py" in do_executemany
  683.             cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)

Exception Type: KeyError at /xxxxx/94feec54-e74e-4596-b42d-f52a53eb631a/yyyyy/
Exception Value: "('first', 'second'"
Request information:
```

Where `SF` is the first index and `monkeys` is the second.  The closing parens is truncated.

I'm using the following df to test it:

```
first         SF                             LA                     
second   monkeys orangutans   girafes   monkeys orangutans   girafes
A      -1.017560   0.354499 -0.446993  1.219814   0.098890  0.717737
B       0.130512  -0.374556  0.536788  0.896989   2.266275  1.539214
C       0.444351   0.155903 -0.238987  1.971802   0.702577  1.215963
```

I've tried to trace this all through the stack and I can confirm Pandas is generating the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "data" (
  "('SF', 'monkeys')" REAL,
  "('SF', 'orangutans')" REAL,
  "('SF', 'girafes')" REAL,
  "('LA', 'monkeys')" REAL,
  "('LA', 'orangutans')" REAL,
  "('LA', 'girafes')" REAL
)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working with SQL Alchemy

Pandas code:

```
dataframe.to_sql(
    '"{}"'.format(self._table_name),
    index=False,
    chunksize=50000,
    con=engine,
)
```

SQLAlchemy engine

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
"postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(
    _warehouse_db_settings["USER"],
    _warehouse_db_settings["PASSWORD"],
    _warehouse_db_settings["HOST"],
    _warehouse_db_settings["PORT"],
    _warehouse_db_settings["NAME"],
    )
)
```

Comment: Please include the traceback, not just a cropped error message, and the exact code that produces the error.

Comment: Good call.  Added traceback.

Comment: please also show a sample from the data frame that you're trying to insert into postgresql

Comment: @HaleemurAli I've included it